# Building realtime messaging app with websockets in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

I want to build a messaging backend service (similar to whatsapp) using spring boot and websockets.

I have look online at the examples of spring boot websockets.

I see how I would send a message to the server from client 1 using the @MessageMapping annotation.

However assuming client 2 (recipient of the message) is also connected to the server with websockets how would I send a message to them.

I have seen the sendToUser annotation however it seems to me that that sends the message to client 1 (the sender of the message).

Is there a map of client ids to websocket sessions or something so that if I know the message should go to (client 2). I can gethis active websocket session and then send him the message?